# Storing Augmenting Path For Maximum Graph Matching

Tags: algorithm, graph, matching

I am trying to write a maximum graph matching algorithm for my thesis. I stuck on how to store the augmenting path on the augmentation step of the algorithm. First, I will write the actual problem I am trying to solve. Then I will try to simplify it.

Suppose you have a graph, where a node can be matched with one of its neighbours and you are trying to calculate the maximum matching. Each node is connected to exactly three other nodes. You did your best, but some nodes left unmatched so you need to do augmentation. At this point, you already know the matchings and the list of nodes that remain unmatched. **Augmentation process works like this:** You pick two nodes from the unmatched nodes list and find an alternating path between them. An **alternating path** consists of the two nodes mentioned and a list of matched nodes in between. It is called an alternating path because matched and unmatched edges between nodes alternate along the path.

You can find an alternating path between any two unmatched nodes, but picking the closer ones are better for the performance of the algorithm. So instead, you pick an unmatched node and do **BFS** until you reach another unmatched node. When you find one such path (which satisfies the alternating path rule), you swap the matchings so the unmatched nodes are now matched.

In short, I need to run some sort of BFS algorithm where there are two types of edges (let's say red and black) and these edges shall alternate along the path until I reach my destination. In the end, I need the path from my source to the closest of the possible destinations which satisfy the red/black rule.

I was able to come up with the pseudocode of the algorithm but I don't know how to store the alternating path that the algorithm finds. How can do it? Any alternative strategies are also welcome.

Comment: Do you intend to run one BFS at a time for each unmatched node, or somehow combine searches for several nodes into one?

Comment: No, it's one BFS at a time which stops when it reaches any unmatched node. This process will be repeated until the list is empty but each search will be a separate call and we are only concerned with a single call.

Comment: Sounds like your BFS could be interested in visiting each node twice: when it discovers it through a red edge, and when it discovers it through a white edge. You could have a map from a tuple (node X, red/black) to the first node that led the BFS to the node X through the edge of corresponding color, and after BFS is finished, traverse this map backwards from final destination to the original node. Does this serve the purpose?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but it doesn't seem like what I wanted. Visiting each node once is enough, the starting and ending edges must be white on any valid path, the rest of the path alternates between red and white. So the opposite of it is not a valid path for me. Finding paths are not a problem but I don't know how to store or trace back the path I found.

Comment: Let's suppose your graph is:
```
1-2
1-3
2-3
2-4
```
And your initial matching has one edge 1-2. Note that the only valid augmenting path here is 3-1-2-4.

If you run a BFS from node 3, it will find nodes 1 and 2 at the same time. If 2 is not visited again from node 1, how does the BFS find 3-1-2-4?

I think it will be easier to suggest answers if you post the code/pseudocode of your BFS.

Comment: I think sharing pseudocode will just complicate the problem so instead, I will try to simplify it to the very basic. Let's forget two different colours of edges. Instead, you are given a huge graph and an even-sized list of selected nodes. My algorithm will pick the first one from the list and run a BFS until it reaches any other node in the list (which is the closest one). I need the path to this node, but I cannot store all of the paths since the input graph can be very big. So what is a valid approach here? If it was a DFS, it would be much easier but augmentation would take much longer.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to label each node X that your BFS visits with the reference to the node from which X was first discovered. I.e., have a map {Node -> Node} where keys are the nodes visited by BFS, and values are their predecessors in the BFS traversal. For example, if the graph has edges 1-2, 1-3, 2-3, 3-4, and BFS is run from node 1, it will map 2 to 1, 3 to 1, and 4 to 3. To reconstruct the full path to node 4, you can traverse this map backwards: 4 -> 3 -> 1. So you spend time and memory proportional to the runtime of BFS itself.

Comment: Will this strategy work when I run multiple searches on the graph? Because I need to do this until the list is empty.

Comment: I believe you'd have to reset the labels after every run of BFS because the next augmenting path might augment along the path found by a previous BFS search. Each separate BFS that starts with no labels works correctly, so if previous BFS "cleans up" after itself next one should work just fine.

Comment: That's what I figured, thanks for your help.

Comment: If this discussion answers your question, I can post it as answer.

Comment: It helps, but I am not sure it completely answers my question yet. See, this algorithm is based on an academic paper material and I need the fully functioning implementation to be able to say that.